# Excel conditional concatenation

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a few columns that am trying to concatenate based off a conditional statement. The columns I have looks like:

```
Col 1    Col 2    Col 3    Col 4    Col 5
  73      NA       NA       NA       NA
```

Am trying to concatenate cells that do not have "NA" or are blanks. I have the following line of code:

```
=IF(OR(B2<>"",B2<>"NA"),CONCATENATE(A2,",",B2),IF(OR(C2<>"",C2<>"NA"),CONCATENATE(A2,",",B2,",",C2),IF(OR(D2<>"",D2<>"NA"),CONCATENATE(A2,",",B2,",",C2,",",D2),IF(OR(E2<>"",E2<>"NA"),CONCATENATE(A2,",",B2,",",C2,",",D2,",",E2),0))))
```

The desired output is

```
73
```

However, I keep getting

```
 73, NA
```

Note: Column 1 will always have a number.

Comment: What Excel are you using?

Comment: You want AND() not OR() in all your statements.

Comment: @ScottCraner am using Excel from Office 365.

Comment: See my Edit#2 then for a much shorter formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner, the result in the second edit 73,0,0,0,0 if columns are empty.

Comment: I think I solved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
=LEFT(IF(AND(A1<>"",A1<>"NA"),A1 & ",","") & IF(AND(B1<>"",B1<>"NA"),B1 & ",","") &IF(AND(C1<>"",C1<>"NA"),C1 & ",","") &IF(AND(D1<>"",D1<>"NA"),D1 & ",","") &IF(AND(E1<>"",E1<>"NA"),E1 & ",",""),LEN(IF(AND(A1<>"",A1<>"NA"),A1 & ",","") & IF(AND(B1<>"",B1<>"NA"),B1 & ",","") &IF(AND(C1<>"",C1<>"NA"),C1 & ",","") &IF(AND(D1<>"",D1<>"NA"),D1 & ",","") &IF(AND(E1<>"",E1<>"NA"),E1 & ",","") )-1)
```

[image]

---

Edit:

It appears as if your data loads sequentially by column.  You can simplify the formula to:

```
=A1 & IF(AND(B1<>"",B1<>"NA"),"," & B1,"")& IF(AND(C1<>"",C1<>"NA"),"," & C1,"")& IF(AND(D1<>"",D1<>"NA"),"," & D1,"")& IF(AND(E1<>"",E1<>"NA"),"," & E1,"")
```

---

Edit #2

If you are using Office 365 Excel then use TextJoin as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF((A1:E1<>"NA")*(A1:E1<>""),A1:E1,""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Comment: in the second edit the result is '73,0,0,0,0' if columns are empty.

Answer (score 1):

The TEXTJOIN function in Excel 2016+ allows ranges as parameters, which combined with an array formula becomes a *conditional* CONCATENATE or "*CONCATENATEIF*".

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(A1:D1<>"NA", A1:D1, ""))
```

Instead of just hitting *Enter*, hit ***Shift + Ctrl + Enter***. This will save it as an array formula, instead of a simple formula. It will be shown different in the formula box.

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(A1:D1<>"NA", A1:D1, ""))}
```

More info about array formulas here.
[Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7)

Answer (score 0):

B2 is "NA", reverse the logic in your `OR`.